# Editable TreeTable in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a project where I use the PrimeFaces Framework. Now I need an tree-organized table, where the cells are editable. I've found an example with OpenFaces, that is exactly what I need:

http://openfaces.org/demo/treetable/TreeTable_selectionAndKeyboard.jsf

is it possible to make that in PrimeFaces?

Comment: Sure, add an inplace tag in each cell

Comment: thanks, inplaces was something new for me. Now I can edit the cells. but the sorting no longer works :(

Comment: So, I was not able to program this example in PrimeFaces. After I added inplace to each cell, it was possible to edit the cells in TreeTable. But the sorting and expand of subtrees no longer works. When someone had experience whith that - please write here.